# How to use an animation for one object on another object?

Tags: animation

I've animated the location of a text object, and now I want to use that same animation on many other text objects at arbitrary times. How can I do this?

Comment: Would [this previous BSE answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15441/how-to-use-an-animation-for-one-object-on-another-object?rq=1) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you keyframed the locations on an object, an action has already been created

- Select the object which should be animated
- Switch to the *Dopesheet* and change to the *Action Editor*
- Assign the action to your object. (default name here is *Textaction*)

Note that the keyframes have absolute coordinates, I you're looking for relative changes you would need to offset them in the NLA-Editor (or alternatively change the origin of the individual text objects).

When you want start animations at different time offsets you would need to place them as Action-Strips in the NLA-Editor there you can move the strips to the time offset they should start (and even scale the duration).

[image]

Comment: I think I'm missing something.. How can I make it so each object using the action plays it at a different time? Currently they all just go at the same time..

Comment: You would need to place them as Action-Strips in the NLA-Editor there you can move the strips to the time offset they should start.